# django: How to get objects from a ContentType instance

Tags: django, django-contenttypes

I want to get a queryset of objects from a ContentType instance and then be able to filter them. From the doc, it is possible to `get()` an object using:

```
ct.get_object_for_this_type(**kwargs)
```

How can I make a similar `filter()` for that instance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you have the ContentType instance you can do `ct.model_class()` to get the model class and then use it as you normally would.

```
model_class = ct.model_class()
model_class.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

As [ContentType model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#the-contenttype-model) has three fields `app_label`, `model` and `name`. So you can easily filter through these fields.

```
notifications = Notification.objects.filter(content_type__model='Comment', object_id=1)
```

Example model:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='notifications', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Object id'))
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    ....
```